# Is there a better way to write this haskell function?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

I just started learning Haskell again (i've already tried a few times) and i wrote a little function, that is supposed to download a file to a given filepath.
If the URL is `Some` it should download the file and if it's `Nothing` it should just do nothing.

```
downloadFile :: URL -> FilePath -> IO ()
downloadFile url fp = ...        

maybeDownloadFile :: Maybe URL -> FilePath -> IO ()
maybeDownloadFile ( Just url ) fp = downloadFile url fp
maybeDownloadFile Nothing fp = return ()
```

So it essentially just wraps the `downloadFile` function, but with a `Maybe URL` instead of a `URL`.
The thing is, I feel like this can be achieved more elegantly with a monadic operator (or maybe with functors) and without the match expression.
Is there some operator like that?

Comment: question is more appropriate for Code Review stack exchange, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking some action on `Just`, and doing nothing on `Nothing`, is exactly what `traverse_` (or `mapM_`) does. Flip your arguments to make it even prettier.

```
downloadFile :: FilePath -> URL -> IO ()
downloadFile fp url = ...

maybeDownloadFile :: FilePath -> Maybe URL -> IO ()
maybeDownloadFile = traverse_ . downloadFile
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is honestly pretty clean. I can look at it and very quickly tell what it does. The top-level pattern match makes it pretty obvious, and the function is short enough to recognize at a glance.

If you *do* want a nice combinator for it, then it turns out one exists. It's called [`whenJust`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.9/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html#v:whenJust) from the `extra` package.

```
maybeDownloadFile :: Maybe URL -> FilePath -> IO ()
maybeDownloadFile url fp = whenJust url (\url -> downloadFile url fp)
```

But it's not that big of a deal. Your current function is fine.

As a side note, I wasn't aware of `whenJust` before now. I found it by searching [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) for the type

```
Maybe a -> (a -> IO ()) -> IO ()
```

i.e. "I have a `Maybe` and want to do an `IO` thing if it's nonempty". `whenJust` was the first result under that search. Hoogle can be a tremendously useful tool for finding things like this, both in the standard library and in related ones.

Comment: Daniel Wagner's answer points out that this is also `traverse_`, which I would expect to be preferable as it's in base. Probably most of these other libraries invented `whenJust` before Traversable got into base, or even before it was invented. When there are a lot of Hoogle results, it's worth fiddling with the argument order to see if you can find a function that doesn't require a dependency on a heavy package like `extra`.